# React Native: Screen not re rendering or triggering useEffect() while using react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to refresh the screen, when the navigation come from a specific page. But when the page navigates, useEffect method or any other method is not getting triggered. I understand that, the method is not getting triggered as the state or props has not changed. But is there a way to trigger it, please let me know. Also I tried didFocus, but it refreshes every time the screen comes into focus, but I want refresh to be done only when it comes from particular screen.

Comment: How do you use the useEffect? Do you have any dependencies on your useEffect? Please share the code for that page that you want to trigger useEffect

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used useEffect yet but i did this with react-navigation to activate a change in props.

On the screen you want to refresh when it gets to it add the didFocus listener:

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'didFocus',
            payload => {
                console.debug('didFocus', payload);
                if (this.props.navigation.getParam('shouldRefresh')) {
                    this.props.navigation.setParams({ shouldRefresh: false });
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        );
```

When you navigate to that screen and want it to refresh:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', { shouldRefresh: true });
```

Hope it helps.